# Bypassing mysqli_connect() error to write unit test

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to write a set of unit tests using PHPUnit (DISCALIMER: This is my first project attempting to use unit tests for improving code quality).

I'm currently have the a `ConnectionManager` class which is managing the connection to the MySQL databases. This class has two member functions:
`GetDBSetLinks` and `ConnectWithMysqli`.

`GetDBSetLinks` is a function that takes in an array of connection information for multiple mysql databases (each element contains Hostname, Username, etc. and some other info), and passes this information into `ConnectWithMysqli`.

`ConnectWithMySqli()` calculates which overload of the `mysqli_connect()` function the program should use to connect the the MySQL database and then calls that overload using the passed in parameters.

When I pass bad connection information (such as a bad password) into `GetDBSetLinks()` using my unit test, the bad information is handled properly makes it to the `ConnectWithMySqli` function as expected. When the bad information hits `mysqli_connect()`, the function fails and triggers the expected

> mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.113' (using password:YES)" error.

The problem is that this also terminates execution of `ConnectWithMySqli()`, thus `ConnectWithMysqli()` will not complete and return the variable that I am trying to test against.

What I would like to do is to keep the program running but trigger an exception that can be handled.

Problem is I just started using `try-catch` and I'm not really sure the best way to do this. Anyone have any ideas?

## Connection.php

```
<?php

class FailedConnection extends Exception{}

class ConnectionManager {
    //FUNCTION: Gets List of Database Links for given database set----------------//
    static public function GetDBSetLinks($CurrentDBSet){
        $DatabaseLinkList = array();

        foreach ($CurrentDBSet as $DatabaseInfoString){
            //Split the Database info string by commas. The input string found in the
            //configuration file is a single string containing all of the parameters
            //needed to connect to the SQL database. The statement below takes this string
            //and converts it into three separate variables, so that they can be passed into mysqli_connect()
            $SplitDBInfo = preg_split('/,/', $DatabaseInfoString);

            //Initialize a variable that serves as an iterator. This variable also holds
            //the number of arguments that were found in the config fie.
            $NumArgs = 0;

            //Initialize other variables necessary to connect to the current database.
            $DatabaseID = "NULL";
            $HostName = "NULL";
            $dbUsername = "NULL";
            $dbPassword = "NULL";
            $DatabaseName = "NULL"; //NOTE: Database name in the config file should exactly match the name of the database on the server.
            $PortNumber = "NULL";
            $Socket = "NULL";

            //Cycle through the individual params now stored in SplitDBInfo, (1.) count
            //them, then (2.) assign them to the appropriate variable to pass into mysqli_connect()
            foreach ($SplitDBInfo as $Parameter){
                $NumArgs ++; //(1.)              
                switch ($NumArgs) { //(2.)
                    case 1:
                        $DatabaseID = $Parameter;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $HostName = $Parameter;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $dbUsername = $Parameter;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $dbPassword = $Parameter;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $DatabaseName = $Parameter;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $PortNumber = $Parameter;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        $Socket = $Parameter;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                //print $Parameter . "<br>"; //DEBUG
            }
            print '<br>' ."NumArgs: " . ($NumArgs) . '<br>'; //DEBUG ONLY
            print "Number of Function Arguments: " . ($NumArgs -1) . '<br>'; //DEBUG ONLY;
            echo "Connecting to Database '" . $DatabaseID . "' at hostname " . $HostName ."." . '<br>';

            $link = self::ConnectWithMysqli($NumArgs, $HostName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $DatabaseName, $PortNumber, $Socket);


            //If our link to the database is not successful, escape this sequence and do not put the link in our list of linked databases.
            if (!$link){
                echo "No Successful link to '" . $DatabaseID . "' at hostname " . $HostName .".";
                echo '<br>';
            }
            //Otherwise, our link should be good, and we should add it to our list of database links.
            else{
                echo "Connection to Database '" . $DatabaseID . "' at hostname " . $HostName ." was successful.";
                echo '<br>';
                array_push($DatabaseLinkList, $link);
            }    
        }
    //After we finish iterating to generate a list of viable links, we can use these
    //links to perform database operations.
    return $DatabaseLinkList;
    }

    function ConnectWithMysqli($NumArgs,$HostName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $DatabaseName, $PortNumber, $Socket){
        switch($NumArgs) {
            case 2:
                $link = mysqli_connect($HostName);
                //could not connect
                break;
            case 3:
                $link = mysqli_connect($HostName,$dbUsername);
                break;
            case 4:
                $link = mysql_connect($HostName,$dbUsername,$dbPassword);
                //$link = mysqli_connect($HostName,$dbUsername,$dbPassword);
                break;
            case 5:
                print ($DatabaseName);
                $link = mysqli_connect($HostName,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$DatabaseName);
                break;
            case 6:
                $link =  mysqli_connect($HostName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $DatabaseName, $PortNumber, $Socket);
                break;
            default:
                throw new FailedConnection;
            }
    try{
        if(!$link){
            throw new FailedConnection;
        }
    }
    catch(FailedConnection $e){
        return "Null";
    }

return $link;
}
```

## ConnectionModuleTest.php

```
<?php
require_once 'C:\Users\bsnider\Documents\BrandonDepot\SourceControl\git\repos\GLS_DBSearchProject\Connection.php';

class ConnectionModuleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    public function setUp(){}
    public function tearDown(){}

    public function testDataGetDBSetLinks_GoodConnection(){
        $ConnectionManager = new ConnectionManager;
        //Valid Connection Parameters
        $DBSet = array('MainDatabase,192.168.1.41,root,colt45', 'MainDatabase,192.168.1.41,root,colt45');
        $Result = $ConnectionManager->GetDBSetLinks($DBSet); //$Result
        $this->assertNotEmpty($Result);
    }

    public function testDataGetDBSetLinks_BadHostName(){
        $ConnectionManager = new ConnectionManager;
        //Invalid Connection Parameters
        $DBSet = array('MainDatabase,192.168.1.20,root,colt45', 'MainDatabase,192.168.1.20,root,colt45');
        $Result = $ConnectionManager->GetDBSetLinks($DBSet); //$Result
        $this->assertEmpty($Result);
    }

    public function testDataGetDBSetLinks_BadPassword(){
        $ConnectionManager = new ConnectionManager;
        //Invalid Connection Parameters
        $DBSet = array('MainDatabase,192.168.1.41,root,badpassword', 'MainDatabase,192.168.1.41,root,badpassword');
        $Result = $ConnectionManager->GetDBSetLinks($DBSet); //$Result
        $this->assertEmpty($Result);        
        }
    public function testConnectWithMysqli(){

    }
}
```

Comment: It's always best to paste your code inline to your question, even if it's long

Comment: Test the ConnectionManager seperately for its error processing. Dont test ConnectionManager as part of a test on some other use case

Comment: I think you might be reinventing the square wheel. Why don't you use or fork one of this libraries : https://packagist.org/search/?q=mysqli  Like https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class , for instance ?

Comment: @Machavity thanks for telling me that. I don't use SxE alot,. I'll be sure to do that next time.

Comment: @greg0ire I'm not quite sure I see how your link would benefit me. I haven't had a ton  of time to look at it, but it looks like that would handle the errors for me, which isn't really what I'm wanting at this point. In terms of reinventing the wheel. Yes, I'm doing a bit of that. As a learning exercise. Thanks for the link though, Didn't know about that when I started.

Comment: packagist is the first thing you must look at if you feel someone already must have solved your problem. Now if you're doing all this as a learning exercise, that's very good, I'll have deeper look at your question

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.errors

Comment: Ahh I see! Packagist is the package repository for composer. Makes a lot more sense now. I'm actually doing both: production and learning. I need to have a good, viable software product at the end of this project, but my boss expects me to learn, and I'm kind-of a novice. (All of my previous programming experience is in C++ and scripting languages). As a result, I like using already put together packages, but I like to make sure I understand mostly what the package is doing when I use it. how everything is working so I can get better.

Comment: Thanks @Steve that's really good to know. Just set up PHPUnit yesterday so I haven't read that much. I'll be sure to go back and finish that up. Also didn't even know annotations were a thing until  I just now. This PHP thing is weird.

Comment: Here is a good resource if you need to learn : http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should attempt to convert all possible errors into exceptions, so that you can use try/catch as you wish.

The first library in [this list](https://packagist.org/search/?q=error) can help you do that.

Comment: Thanks for this. Haven't accepted the answer yet because I'm not 100% sure what route I'm going to take with this. @all Thanks for the info and help.